# Unsigned long hexadecimal representation

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[256] = {};
    unsigned long i=13835058055298940928;
    snprintf(buf, 1024, "%lx", i); /* Line 7 */
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

In line 7, if I use `%lux`, and then `snprintf` doesn't do any conversion. It just prints `0x13835058055298940928x`, whereas if I use just `%lx`, it prints an expected hexadecimal conversion.

How do I represent unsigned long in hexadecimal?

Comment: Hexadecimal doesn't care about signed or unsigned - x is all you need.

Comment: `%lux` seems to be treated as `%lu` + `x`

Comment: And you pass `1024` in place of `256` as the buffer space

Comment: You're not really trying to put 13835058055298940928 into an unsigned long, are you? On my system (win7 x64) the sizeof(long) is 4 - i.e it's 32 bits long. That gives you a maximum value for 32 unsigned bits as being: 4294967295. See the problem here? You're trying to stuff an elephant into a rabbit-cage. All bets are off automatically!! In fact, your number is 3,221,225,472.75 times as large as the largest number you can put into 32 bits. It's 75% of the largest number you can hold in an unsigned 64 bit representation..

Comment: @PaulR: Hexadecimal (`"%x"` format) doesn't care about signed; unsigned is all you *get*.

Comment: @enhzflep: On *some* systems, `unsigned long` is 64 bits. Storing `13835058055298940928` in an `unsigned long` is non-portable, but it does work on some systems.

Answer (score 20):

A format of `"%lux"` is treated as `"%lu"` (unsigned long, decimal) followed by a letter `x`.

The `"%x"` format requires an argument of unsigned type; there's no (direct) mechanism to print signed integers in hexadecimal format.

The format for printing an `unsigned long` value in hexadecimal is `"%lx"`. (`x` is hexadecimal, `d` is signed decimal, `u` is unsigned decimal; any of them may be qualified with `l` for long.)

Note that the value `13835058055298940928` requires at least a 64-bit unsigned type to store it without overflow. The type `unsigned long` is at least 32 bits; it's 64 bits on *some* systems, but by no means all. If you want your code to be portable, you should use type `unsigned long long` rather than `unsigned long`. The format for printing an `unsigned long long` value in hexadecimal is `"%llx"`.

For clarity, I usually precede hexadecimal output with `0x`, so it's obvious to the reader that it's a hexadecimal number:

```
printf("0x%llx\n", some_unsigned_long_long_value);
```

(You can achieve the same result with `%#llx`, but I find it easier to write out `0x` than to remember the meaning of the `#` flag.)

Comment: Gets my vote. A much better and more thorough covering of 32/64 bit details - particularly those regarding portability. :thumbsup:

Comment: If you need an unsigned 64 bit integer; use `uint64_t`, `uint_least64_t` or , `uint_fast64_t` to ask for an unsigned 64 bit integer. `unsigned long long` should be (but sadly isn't) considered an archaic and deprecated synonym for `uint_fast64_t` (in the same way that `int` should be, but sadly isn't, considered an archaic and deprecated synonym for `int_fast16_t`). ;-)