# warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

When I try and compile this I get the following error, not sure why...

> warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
>
> ```
> printf("Name buffer address:    %x\n", buffer);
> ```

The code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
        char name[200];
        printf("What is your name?\n");
        scanf("%s", name);
        bo(name, "uname -a");
}

int bo(char *name, char *cmd){
        char c[40];
        char buffer[40];
        printf("Name buffer address:    %x\n", buffer);
        printf("Command buffer address: %x\n", c);
        strcpy(c, cmd);
        strcpy(buffer, name);
        printf("Goodbye, %s!\n", buffer);
        printf("Executing command: %s\n", c);
        fflush(stdout);
        system(c);
}
```

Comment: Related question I found very helpful for my particular case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478509/unsigned-long-hex-representation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are getting the warnings because of the following statements

```
    printf("Name buffer address:    %x\n", buffer);
    printf("Command buffer address: %x\n", c);
```

`%x` expects an `unsigned int`, whereas you're supplying a pointer.

To refer, `C11` standard, chapter §7.21.6.1

> `o,u,x,X`
>  The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned
>   decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal notation (x or X) in the style dddd; [...]

Supplying invalid argument invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should be using `%p` to print the address

> `p` The argument shall be a pointer to `void`.[...]

and cast the argument to `void *`, because for pointer types  no *default argument promotion* takes place.

Having said that,

1. `main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least, to conform to the standard.
2. You need to forward declare your function `bo()` because implicit declarations are *bad* and  non-standard now.

Answer (score 8):

To print an address use `"%p"` instead of `"%x"`. You also need to cast to `void *`

```
printf("Name buffer address:    %p\n", (void *) buffer);
```